# If a compact real submanifold of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is approximable by complex algebraic curves, is it algebraic?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

To make this into a separate question:

*If the supports of a sequence of complex algebraic curves in $\mathbb{CP}^n$ (images of non-constant holomorphic maps from compact Riemann surfaces) converge to a real compact immersed submanifold $M \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$, must this submanifold $M$ be complex (algebraic)?*

For some motivation for this problem, see here:

[If there is a dense geodesic, are almost all geodesics equidistributed? Dense?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176629/if-there-is-a-dense-geodesic-are-almost-all-geodesics-equidistributed-dense)

Note that if $M$ is complex algebraic, there is certainly a sequence of complex algebraic curves with supports converging to $M$. (In fact, they could be taken lie in $M$). What I ask about is the converse. Unless it has an easy counterexample, this question is somewhat in the spirit of a few famous problems about special subvarieties in diophantine geometry, such as the Manin-Mumford and Andre-Oort questions, or Lang's algebro-geometric conjecture.

Comment: If the convergence is in the Hausdorff topology for compact sets then M is complex algebraic if there is a bound on the degrees of the sequence .In this case M only needs to be a nonempty closed set .This follows from Bishop's convergence theorem for analytic sets along with Chow's theorem .This also works if you have a sequence of pure p dimensional algebraic sets .

Comment: Thank you for noting this! In this case of bounded degrees, the conclusion is thus that $M$ is in fact an algebraic curve (resp. algebraic set of dimension $p$). I am interested, though, primarily in the case where $M$ is higher dimensional, with the curves wrapping around it and therefore - necessarily - having degrees going to infinity (which is indeed easily seen to be possible if $M$ is complex algebraic).

Comment: And yes, I do mean convergence in the Hausdorff topology for compact sets. By the way, I would also like to know whether the submanifold $M$ must be compact - even if we assume from the outset that the limit $M$ is a complex submanifold (or the closure of a complex submanifold).

Comment: Yes M will be compact.One does not need any additional assumptions .

Comment: Commenting to point out that there is a literature studying a different notion of convergence: Thinking of $\frac{1}{\deg Z_i} \int_{Z_i}$ as a linear functional on smooth $(1,1)$-forms and looking at the limit in the space of linear functionals on $\Omega^{(1,1)}$ with the weak topology. See http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=679762 and the papers that cite it. But I don't see how to make this relevant to Hausdorff convergence.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: This means looking at the $Z_i$ as defining closed, positive $(1,1)$-currents of integration (normalized to have total mass one). Then their limit, if it exists, is also closed and positive as $(1,1)$-current, but it need not be an analytic cycle. (I think a counterexample is contained in the paper you pointed to?) Even if the limit is an analytic cycle $Z$, though, this $Z$ is certainly of complex dimension one, whereas the problem with the Hausdorff notion of convergence is most interesting when the $M$ has $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}{M} > 2$, with the complex curves wrapping around it.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Taking $Z_d$ to be the degree $d$ Fermat curve in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, as in Demailly's paper, the supports converge in the Hausdorff topology to the set $S$  consisting of those $[z_0:z_1:z_2]$ having $|z_i| \leq |z_k| = |z_l|$ for some permutation $i,j,k$ of $0,1,2$. This is not exactly a real manifold, but it comes close; and it is not algebraic. This suggests that the answer to my question is negative.